# Microsoft Azure - Virtual Network

Tags: azure, endpoint, azure-virtual-network

I'm starting to use the cloud service of Microsoft Azure and I have a question about Virtual Networks.

I created a virtual network, without dns server, and allocate two virtual machines in this virtual network.
So I ran one service in my virtual machine that have a web interface on port 4040.
But I can't access this port from my local machine, like:

public_ip:4040 
or 
internal_ip: 4040

I added an endpoint to port 4040 in this machine in my manage portal and the result is the same.

Can anyone suggest something to try?
This kind of operation is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a firewall between your machine and the azure cloud you need to have opened the port 4040 for your machine.

Comment: Hum.. I'll do this test and after I reply the result. Thanks!

Comment: @DaniloPinto: Can you `ping` the vm in the cloud?

Comment: It really was the firewall. =)

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on flagging-off your Azure Journey!

I assume these are windows servers that you have them deployed. I have elaborated some of the troubleshooting that you can do:

1. You would have an NSG attached to the VM NIC/Subnet. Kindly proceed to create an inbound rule to Allow 4040 from your specific public IP from where you are trying to access the VM.
2. Now, do a nestat -ano | Findstr 4040 from your cmd and see if it's listening
3. Should you have them both, now turnoff your windows firewall from all profiles

After which, you can take a network capture using easy to go tools such as Wireshark/network monitor on the VM's or if you are using a Linux VM. Simple TCPdump.

While you are collecting captures, keep in mind to initiate traffic from your client IP to the respective Public IP:4040

Narrow down the issue:
 - If the packets are incoming with destination port 4040. No issues with Azure
 - If the 4040 is not listening, the service needs to listen on that port
 - Put the firewall back on and see if the TCP packets are still coming on 4040
 - If none of this works, it's highly unlikely for that port to be used. So, you can give 
   it a restart and check the same.

But, I highly recommend network captures with continuous TCP ping on to the port 4040.

I hope this helps. Should you have any difficulty with network captures use the links below:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucascan/2007/08/15/using-microsoft-network-monitor-netmon-to-capture-a-network-trace/
Psping: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping
http://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/PsPing